# JQuery or JavaScript - Count how many array elements are true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an instance where arrays of potentially different length can look like this...

```
Array [ true, false, false, true ]
```

Or

```
Array [ true, true, true, false, true ]
```

Or

```
Array [ true, true, true ]
```

I need to iterate through an array and ONLY trigger a new event if there is ONE instance of "false".

Out of sample arrays I presented,, this one wold be the only one that is valid

```
Array [ true, true, true, false, true ]
```

What would be the least elaborate way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it by using `Array.filter`

```
var arr = [ true, true, true, false, true ];
if(arr.filter(function(b){ return !b; }).length == 1){
   // trigger the event
}
```

The above filters to just contain `Array` of `false` and then we check if the `length` of that `Array` is `1`

Another creative way of doing this might be using `replace` and `indexOf`, where you're just replacing the first occurrence of `false` in a `String` formed by joining the `arr` and checking if there are still any `false` in the string and negate it with `!` operator to achieve the results.

```
if(!(arr.join("").replace("false","").indexOf("false") > -1)){
  // trigger
}
```

Comment: I will test this in a minute. It looks like it will do well for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @GRowing sure. Glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 4):

Amit Joki already has a [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27415703/558592), but I'd just like to share another solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var count = arr.reduce(function(prevVal, currVal) {
    return prevVal + (!currVal ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);

if (count === 1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion too. Thanks for pitching in :)